# Raspberry Pi Won't Boot (Only Red LED On)

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+. For several months it worked perfectly fine, but one day it just stopped booting and only getting to the red LED. I've tried buying a new microSD but the same behavior keeps happening. Is there anything else I can try or do I have to buy a new Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many experiences about why a Raspberry Pi don't boot anymore. You will find a wide collection about reasons at the official Raspberry Pi forum. Following the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) I'm sure you will find what's your problem and if you have to purchase a new RasPi.